How to change directory path of ASP.NET Web API build?
After building my ASP.NET Web API and uploading it to the server, I created an application for it in IIS and have been trying to get it to run, but it keeps returning an IIS 502.5 error. After ensuring the server had the latest ASP.NET runtime, the error still kept happening, so I checked the event viewer on the server and found this error.
Application: WebAppsCoreClone.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.1024.46610
.NET Version: 8.0.10
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\Documents\Web Dev\WebAppsCoreClone\WebAppsCoreClone\wwwroot\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.<>c.<UseStaticWebAssetsCore>b__1_0(String contentRoot)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider..ctor(StaticWebAssetManifest manifest, Func`2 fileProviderFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at WebAppsCoreClone.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Web Dev\WebAppsCoreClone\WebAppsCoreClone\Program.cs:line 28

The error at line 28 in Program.cs is CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); in
namespace WebAppsCoreClone
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
           .CreateLogger();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        /*public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog();*/
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

    }
}

The directory file path it's trying to access is actually a path on my own pc, so when the runtime trys to access while being on the server machine, it crashes.
The problem is I don't know how to change this directory path to the app's location on the server. I tried using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() and also setting the Directory to that in StartUp.cs, but it's still not working. The same error is still being thrown
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, AspNetCoreHosting env, ApplicationDbContextSeedData seeder)
{
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());

    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseAuthentication();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"UploadFolder")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/UploadFolder")
    });

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    seeder.SeedAsync().Wait();

    
}


post what you have tried so far in StartUp.cs and what is at Program.cs:line 28

@Bender Done, thanks for letting me know

the .pdb files contain the path to sources at the time they were built, so you're seeing DEV machine's source code path, thats normal debug info https://www.codementor.io/@rowlandbanks/cleaner-stacktraces-13q3hbv2s7

Please make sure the wwwroot folder and its contents are correctly published to the server. During deployment, the project files (including the wwwroot folder) should be copied to the correct location on the server. Verify that the wwwroot folder exists in the directory where your application is deployed.

@meiquan the wwwroot folder has already been copied into the directory

what is the .net version with which you are building the app? is it same as server installed version i.e. .net 8, it seems you have created the project with older version of .net

@Bender I haven't been able to test removing app.UseStaticFiles yet but will get back to you soon on that, as for the version: the app was originally built in 2.2, but I migrated the app to a 8.0 project by copy pasting the code over. The server has already been installed with both 2.2 and 8.0 runtimes, sdk and hosting services

You can also try use failed request tracing to see details about 502.5 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@Bender I tried removing app.UseStaticFiles but the error persists
